# Existe alguma forma de interpretar (parser) de uma connection string para um objeto?

Tags: c#, connectionstring

Existe uma determinada biblioteca que estou usando onde preciso passar separadamente como parâmetro, separadamente, o valores de conexão com o banco de dados: Username, Password, Host e Database.

Eu peguei esse projeto  e outra pessoa, e notei que o programador, além da connectionString usada para a configuração padrão do banco, definiu separadamente esses mesmos dados através do `<appSettings>` usando o  `<add key="Key" value="Value">` para implementar especificamente para essa tal biblioteca citada acima.

Eu não achei isso uma boa ideia, já que eu teoricamente estaria repetindo a mesma configuração que já tenho, só que a diferença é que a mesma está escrita em `connectionString`.

Eu queria saber se existe alguma maneira de transformar uma `connectionString` em uma estrutura de chave/valor.

Por exemplo, gostaria que essa `string` abaixo se tornasse em um objeto ou dicionário.

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Target_Database;User Id=User; Password=MyPassword"
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como você pode garantir o formato da *string* pode fazer algo assim:

```
var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;

var dicionario = cs.Split(';').ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=')[0], 
                                            x => x.Split('=')[1], 
                                            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FtqgQN)

Isso vai retornar um dicionário com esta estrutura

```
[Data Source, .\SQLEXPRESS]  
[Initial Catalog, Target_Database]  
[User Id, User]  
[Password, MyPassword]
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma sugestão é usar Regex com e adicionar os resultados em um dicionário, a regex seria assim:

```
([^\\s].*?)=([^;]+?)(;|$)

 ^     ^     ^        ^
 |     |     |        |
 |     |     |        |
 |     |     |        +---- Verifica se é o final da string
 |     |     |              ou se encontra um ponto virgula
 |     |     |        
 |     |     +------------- Busca o "valor" até encontrar um ;
 |     |             
 |     +------------------- Busca qualquer coisa que representa a chave
 |                  
 +------------------------- A chave não pode extrair o espaço que vier no prefixo
```

O código deve ficar mais ou menos assim

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> configuracoes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        string re = "([^\\s].*?)=([^;]+?)(;|$)";

        string input = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Target_Database;User Id=User; Password=MyPassword";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, re)) {
            //Salva o item
            configuracoes[m.Groups[1].Value] = m.Groups[2].Value;
        }

        //Pegando os itens do dicionário
        Console.WriteLine("Valor: {0}", configuracoes["Data Source"]); // Retorna .\SQLEXPRESS
        Console.WriteLine("Valor: {0}", configuracoes["Initial Catalog"]); // Retorna Target_Database
        Console.WriteLine("Valor: {0}", configuracoes["User Id"]); // Retorna User
        Console.WriteLine("Valor: {0}", configuracoes["Password"]); // Retorna MyPassword
    }
}
```

**Notas:**

- O `.Groups[1]` pega o que esta dentro dos parenteses `([^\\s].*?)`
- O `.Groups[2]` pega o que esta dentro dos parenteses `([^;]+?)`

> O `.Groups[0]` pegaria o "match" todo, e o `.Groups[3]` pegaria o `(;|$)`, mas não vamos usar nenhum deles

Exemplo no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/099UDD)

Answer (score 3):

Eu também gostaria de dar os meus dois centavos aqui.

Depois de dar uma vasculhada no [Stackoverflow inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28411175/3096922), aprendi que existe uma classe específica para fazer esse trabalho: `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder`.

Eu Fiz um exemplo abaixo apenas para demonstrar como seria o uso da mesma.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Common;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();

        builder.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Target_Database;User Id=User; Password=MyPassword";

        Console.WriteLine(builder["data source"]);
    }
}
```

Você pode acessar os valores de `builder` através do nome da opção utilizada no `connectionString`. Não há diferença entre maiúsculas e minúsculas, então poderia ser usado também `builder["Data Source"]` para acessar o valor dessa propriedade.

**DICA**: Se for necessário checar, antes de usar, se uma propriedade existe, basta utilizar o método `ContainsKey()`. Ele retornará `false` caso a chave passada não exista.